# Name for words with same number of letters (size)?

Tags: single-word-requests

There's anagrams, lexigrams, palindromes and many others... But is there a name for words that have the same "size"/"length" (number of characters)?

For instance, "car" and "bat" both have 3 characters. "Eggs" and "near" both have four. Is there a special word for the size/length-based relationships these words share?

Comment: They're 3-letter words and 4-letter words?

Comment: Thanks @Hellion (+1) but is it really that simple? There isn't some special name for them, like "*sizeindromes*", that means "words with same numbers of letters"?

Comment: I don't think their is an equivalent to saying "bat is an anagram of tab". But you could say something like "car and bat are equi-length words".

Comment: I don't believe that there's a special word for the general relationship, as in "cat/bar and paper/tiger are pairs of equal-letter-count words".

Comment: No, you can invent one if you like, but don't be surprised if it doesn't catch on. Most people have no use for such a term. TLAs and ETLAs do the job pretty well already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"**Homomegete**", from μέγεθος = size ; in French "homoméguète".

Comment: Neither the English nor the French version exists according to google.

Comment: Let it be so! From this point forward, words with the same "string size" (character length) will be known as **homomegetes**!

Comment: Homage to homomegetes!

Comment: ELU, not DIY...