# Is there a word (or phrase) meaning related words that have the same number of letters?

Tags: single-word-requests

It's *possible* that [homomegete](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/130740/10173) is the best, but I'm thinking of things like:

```
username
password
```

or

```
user
pass
```

and

```
nervous
excited
```

I've had other sorts of pairings that I've come across over the years (`host/port`)... and I really *really* like that kind of paring, especially when I'm programming. I'd love to be able to be able to say

> Ah, I love writing *something* when I'm programming!

I could say

> Ah, I love writing homomegetes when I'm programming!

But that's not quite precise enough, I feel.

Is there a word for these parings, or is homomegete the best I'll get?

Comment: Would a prefixed word meaning 'related' work? Not sure if there will be a *single* word...

Comment: @marcellothearcane yeah, that would work